# Redirect beating out URL path and creating redirect loop

Tags: redirection, path-aliases

Currently ran a bunch of updates on our site, and we're experiencing this issue:

- Create nodea at /nodea
- Change nodea's path to /nodeb

  - a redirect will be written added to nodeb: /nodea -> /nodeb
- Create a new new node, and call it nodea, so the URL path then becomes /nodea for it
- If you try to go to the new /nodea page, the redirect rule catches it first and sends you to /nodeb

I'm not sure what caused this, and it's a huge issue. (That example is, of course, just to show what's occurring; it's not the exact use case, but pretty close.)

Can anyone give me an idea on how to fix this? Or at least where to start looking?

Comment: What is your pathauto rule for renaming? If you don't want the old url to be reusable, then set it to keep the old alias and create a new one. Thus the new nodea would have the path /nodea-0 instead of /nodea if /nodea is already taken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has since been corrected with an update to the [redirect](http://drupal.org/redirect) module.

There's now an "enabled" field on redirects, and when a conflict occurs (e.g. a new active alias is entered when that path is already a redirect), the redirect becomes disabled.